# Msbuild WebDirectorySetting doesn't set enabledProtocols setting

Tags: iis-7, msbuild, application-settings, msbuildcommunitytasks

I trying create iis7 web application by msbuild community tasks and set property "Enabled Protocols" to "http,net.tcp", but this property doesn't set (I am checking in `inetmgr`):

```
<Project DefaultTargets="CreateSite" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <VirtualDirectoryName>DCSS_dev_s7</VirtualDirectoryName>
    <VirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\DCSS_dev_s7</VirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CreateSite">
    <WebDirectoryDelete VirtualDirectoryName="$(VirtualDirectoryName)" ContinueOnError="true" />
    <WebDirectoryCreate VirtualDirectoryName="$(VirtualDirectoryName)" VirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath="$(VirtualDirectoryPhysicalPath)" />
    <WebDirectorySetting VirtualDirectoryName="$(VirtualDirectoryName)" SettingName="enabledProtocols" SettingValue="http,net.tcp" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

How I can set this property by msbuild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enabledProtocols` isn't part of the [IIS global properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720489%28WS.10%29.aspx) so `WebDirectorySetting` ignores it.

Instead use [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com) IIS tasks which are more updated than MSBuildCommunityTasks.

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7Binding 
    TaskAction="Add" 
    Name="NewSite" 
    BindingInformation="192.168.1.101:8080:stackoverflow.com" 
    BindingProtocol="http"/>
```